# There exists a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = \infty , \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_nf(x_n)=\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|dt<\infty.$$
Prove that there exists a sequence of real numbers $(x_n)$ such that 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = \infty , \lim_{n \rightarrow
\infty}x_nf(x_n)=\infty.$$

This is one of my past exam questions. I have no idea how to start at all. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is $f(x)=0$ not a counterexample?

Comment: I strongly suspect the actual question has $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n f(x_n) = 0$.  
The point being that if this did not hold, there would be some $\epsilon > 0$ such that  $|f(x)| \ge \epsilon/ x$ for all sufficiently large $x$.  And then use the comparison test...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, an argument like $f \in L^1 \Rightarrow f \rightarrow 0$ faster than $\frac{1}{x}$ (loosely speaking) should work. Is the converse (which you asked about and deleted in comments) true?

Comment: No, e.g. $1/(x \log x)$ goes to $0$ faster than $1/x$ but is still not integrable at $\infty$.